# Read multiple tables in from a single text file?

Tags: r, text-files

I have a single .txt file with a number of tables in it. Is there a way to read each of these into its own data frame? Each 'table' is preceded by a line with its title on it, so I can search for those titles.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to read in the entire file, then parse it for your table headers or empty lines.  I'd make the headers a var that you set and have it be at the top of the script for you to change easily if/when you make changes to the tables in your txt file.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So I have the whole thing read with `lines <- scan(inFile, what="character", sep="\n")`. The first table has the title on the first line and the header in the first row and the row.names in the first column. The data part of the table is always 32 lines long. How do I grab that first table?

Comment: I would have used readLines (because I know what I will get) and then used segments as input: eg.  `read.table(textConnection(lines[2:33])`

Answer (score 1):

Simple google search returned this. 
Worked perfectly for me.

```
> x <- readLines(textConnection("1
+ Pietje
+ I1 I2 Value
+ 1  1  0.11
+ 1  2  0.12
+ 2  1  0.21
+
+ 2
+ Jantje
+ I1 I2 I3 Value
+ 1  1  1  0.111
+ 3  3  3  0.333"))
> closeAllConnections()
> start <- grep("^[[:digit:]]+$", x)
> mark <- vector('integer', length(x))
> mark[start] <- 1
> # determine limits of each table
> mark <- cumsum(mark)
> # split the data for reading
> df <- lapply(split(x, mark), function(.data){
+     .input <- read.table(textConnection(.data), skip=2, header=TRUE)
+     attr(.input, 'name') <- .data[2]  # save the name
+     .input
+ })
> # rename the list
> names(df) <- sapply(df, attr, 'name')
> df
$Pietje
  I1 I2 Value
1  1  1  0.11
2  1  2  0.12
3  2  1  0.21

$Jantje
  I1 I2 I3 Value
1  1  1  1 0.111
2  3  3  3 0.333
```

[Source](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-May/161628.html).